# send email from bootstrap framework My error in this is i got a message is Mail sent successfully but i didn't receive any mail

Tags: javascript, php, twitter-bootstrap, sendmail

Form to send email from bootstrap frame work is that any thing i need to do extra work like adding phpmailer or need to change in php.ini file or need to setup any mail function

**html code**

```
<form name="sentMessage" id="contactForm" novalidate>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Your Name *" name="name" id="name" required data-validation-required-message="Please enter your name.">
                <p class="help-block text-danger"></p>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="email" class="form-control" placeholder="Your Email *" name= "email" id="email" required data-validation-required-message="Please enter your email address.">
                <p class="help-block text-danger"></p>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="tel" class="form-control" placeholder="Your Phone *" name="phone" id="phone" required data-validation-required-message="Please enter your phone number.">
                <p class="help-block text-danger"></p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <div class="form-group">
                <textarea class="form-control" placeholder="Your Message *" name="message" id="message" required data-validation-required-message="Please enter a message."></textarea>
                <p class="help-block text-danger"></p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="clearfix"></div>
        <div class="col-lg-12 text-center">
            <div id="success"></div>
            <button type="submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-xl">Send Message</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

**js Codes**

```
$(function () {
    $("input,textarea").jqBootstrapValidation({
        preventSubmit: true,
        submitError: function ($form, event, errors) {
            // additional error messages or events
        },
        submitSuccess: function ($form, event) {
            event.preventDefault(); // prevent default submit behaviour

            // get values from FORM
            var name = $("input#name").val();
            var email = $("input#email").val();
            var phone = $("input#phone").val();
            var message = $("textarea#message").val();
            var firstName = name; // For Success/Failure Message
            // Check for white space in name for Success/Fail message
            if (firstName.indexOf(' ') >= 0) {
                firstName = name.split(' ').slice(0, -1).join(' ');
            }
            $.ajax({
                url: "././mail/contact_me.php",
                type: "POST",
                data: {
                    name: name,
                    phone: phone,
                    email: email,
                    message: message
                },
                cache: false,
                success: function () {
                    // Success message

                    $('#success').html("<div class='alert alert-success'>");
                    $('#success > .alert-success').html("<button type='button' class='close' data-dismiss = 'alert' aria - hidden = 'true' > & times; ").append("</button>");
                    $('#success > .alert-success').append("<strong>Your message has been sent. </strong>");
                    $('#success > .alert-success').append('</div>');
                    //clear all fields
                    $('#contactForm').trigger("reset");
                },
                error: function () {
                    // Fail message
                    $('#success').html("<div class='alert alert-danger'>");
                    $('#success > .alert-danger').html("<button type='button' class='close' data-dismiss = 'alert' aria - hidden = 'true' > & times; ").append("</button>");
                    $('#success > .alert-danger').append("<strong>Sorry " + firstName + ", it seems that my mail server is not responding.Please try again later!");
                    $('#success > .alert-danger').append('</div>');
                    //clear all fields
                    $('#contactForm').trigger("reset");
                },
            })
        },
        filter: function () {
            return $(this).is(":visible");
        },
    });
    $("a[data-toggle=\"tab\"]").click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $(this).tab("show");
    });
});
/*When clicking on Full hide fail/success boxes */
$('#name').focus(function () {
    $('#success').html('');
});
```

**This is my php file**

```
<?php

// Check for empty fields
if (empty($_POST['name']) || empty($_POST['email']) || empty($_POST['phone']) || empty($_POST['message']) || !filter_var($_POST['email'], FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
    echo "No arguments Provided!";
    return false;
}

$name = $_POST['name'];
$email_address = $_POST['email'];
$phone = $_POST['phone'];
$message = $_POST['message'];

// Create the email and send the message
$to = 'prasanna.venkatesan83@gmail.com'; // Add your email address inbetween the '' replacing yourname@yourdomain.com - This is where the form will send a message to .
$email_subject = "Website Contact Form:  $name";

$email_body = "You have received a new message from your website contact form.\n\n" . "Here are the details:\n\nName: $name\n\nEmail: $email_address\n\nPhone: $phone\n\nMessage:\n$message";

$headers = "From: prasanna.venkatesan83@gmail.com\n"; // This is the email address the generated message will be from. We recommend using something like noreply@yourdomain.com.
$headers .= "Reply-To: $email_address";

$mail = @mail($to, $email_subject, $email_body, $headers);

if (!$mail->send()) {
    echo "Cannot send e-mail";
    echo 'Mailer Error: ' . $mail->ErrorInfo;
    exit;
}
echo "e-mail Has Been Sent To Your Email Address.";
return true;
?>
```

Comment: Are you getting an issue or asking for review of your code?

Comment: You can't boostrap is not server side. You create the form with bootstrap but it alone can not send mail

Comment: i am asking for the problem only mail is been not sending by using this code so only i posted these codes. @clonerworks

Comment: Then how can i send email from bootstrap frame work @exussum

Comment: On the server is this running for you have a local mail server or using an STMP server at all?

Comment: using SMTP server only @clonerworks

Comment: Is there more code cause there is no connection to an SMTP server here?

Comment: The php file is server side and the only code you need. The fact you use bootstrap doesn't matter. Also why @mail ?

Comment: for SMTP connection i change the content in php.ini file other than that any thing i need to change for SMTP connection

Comment: personally i think you need to use - http://swiftmailer.org/

Comment: Other than my code anything i need to add or change like Phpmailer help me to sole this @exussum

Comment: how can i use that swiftmailer it will works perfectly in bootstrap  is the doubt i have @clonerworks

Comment: Please edit your post to be very clear where the issue is as currently your not providing enough information to assist you. Is the javascript sending the information to the php file or is it not? Please check your browser console when submitting the form to see if you get any errors.

Comment: Yeah when ever user submit that it sends data to js file from js it sends data to php @clonerworks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the issue your facing is due to the built in php mail function not sending mail.
I recommend you use an external library such as swiftmail to send the mail for you.

Because we cannot see your smtp setting due to them been in your php.ini file which is not posted here we cannot evaluate them for you.

Your comments appear to point to the face the code is working fine but the mail is not sending as such the issue is with the php mail code.

Comment: What are the changes i need to change in my php.ini file to send mail to gmail account

Comment: As i stated you havent shown the php.ini file so i cannot advise if the settings you have put in there are correct.

Comment: This is my php.ini file mail settings

Comment: [mail function]
    ; XAMPP: Comment out this if you want to work with an SMTP     Server like Mercury
    ; SMTP = localhost
    ; smtp_port = 25

    ; For Win32 only.
    ; http://php.net/sendmail-from
    ;sendmail_from = postmaster@localhost

Comment: Try here - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15965376/how-to-configure-xampp-to-send-mail-from-localhost

Comment: If you sending your mail externally what domain are you sending it from? postmaster@localhost will not work because localhost is not a valid domain example.com is however. Are you able to check logs to and see if there are any errors?

Comment: `\xampp\php\logs\php_error_log` or `\xampp\apache\logs\error.log`i think, i havent used xampp in years, i use vagrant. BTW here is a link to the xampp support forum - https://community.apachefriends.org/f/viewforum.php?f=16&sid=96dfe1ef23393269f151afa5fcffd6cb

Comment: the error is [22-Dec-2014 11:26:47 Europe/Berlin] PHP Fatal error:  Call to a member function send() on boolean in C:\xampp\htdocs\page\contact_me.php on line 25